# Wierd behaviour on regexp Matcher

Tags: java, regex

My regexp below is supposed to filter out capital words with a length of 8-10, where 0-2 numbers may appear. It has been working for all of my tests, but for some reason it got stuck on the string below. And `n.group(0)` only contains an empty string instead of the matched "word".

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = 
    Pattern.compile("\\b(?=[A-Z\\d]{9,10}\\b)(?:[A-Z]*\\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\\b");

Matcher n = LONG_PASSWORD.matcher("foo ID:636152727 bar");

while (n.find()) {
    String s = n.group(0);                  
    resultArrayList.add(s);
}
```

Why does my pattern match `ID:636152727`?

Some examples that I want to filter out (which is working):

- AAAAAAAAAA
- 1AAAAAAAAA
- 1AAAAAAAA1

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to use anchors `^` and `$` »</strike>

```
Pattern.compile("^(?=[A-Z\\d]{9,10}$)(?:[A-Z]*\\d){0,2}[A-Z]*$");
```

Use this pattern:

```
"(?:^|(?<=\\s))(?=[A-Z\\d]{9,10}(?:\\s|$))(?:[A-Z]*\\d){0,2}[A-Z]*(?=\\s|$)"
```

Comment: Hmm ok, but did you miss something? Because if i try it on the string "AAAAAAAAA1 AAAAAAAA11 AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB9", I dont get any matches.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working. But I cant figure out why I got a match on "ID:636152727" with my pattern. For starters, it has a length of 12. Have any idea? :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a better solution to offer than the one in Ωmega's answer, but I think I can explain what's happening.  What it boils down to is that the first `\b` and the last `\b` are matching the same spot: right after the colon.

That's the first place where the lookahead can match, since it's followed by nine digits and a word boundary.  Then the next part of the regex tries to match two digits (interspersed with any number of uppercase letters) followed by a word boundary, and fails.  So it tries to match just one digit (ditto), and fails again.  Then it tries matching *zero* digits (interspersed with *zero* letters), and it succeeds, without advancing the match position.  That position is still a word boundary, so the final `\b` succeeds as well.

A word boundary is just another zero-width assertion, like lookaheads and lookbehinds.  There's no reason why two or more can't be applied at the same spot; you did that on purpose with the first word boundary and the lookahead.  Some regex flavors treat it as an error if you apply a *quantifier* to an assertion (like `\b+`), but I don't think any of them would catch this problem.  This is one of those rare instances where separate start-of-word and end-of-word assertions, like GNU's `\<` and `\>` or TCL's `\y` and `\Y`, would make a difference.